# Access pointer methods of pointer vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not really sure how to phrase the question exactly correctly, but I've declared two vectors

```
std::vector<enemy*> enemies;
std::vector<hit_area *> effects;
```

these work and are fine, however I pass them to a function with

```
handleGame(strd_maps[0], &gcam, &mainchar, currentKeyStates, &enemies, &effects)
```

which works and is fine, however in the function, when I try to access members or methods or enemies or effect

```
if(effects[d]->collide(enemies[i]->x, enemies[i]->y enemies[i]->w, enemies[i]->h))
```

I get the error "base operand of "->" has non-pointer type 'std::vector*'. 
I can access the size of both enemies and effects, it's just accessing the methods that is giving problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you don't pass the address of a vector. Instead, you pass a reference:

```
void func(std::vector<enemy*> &enemies) {
std::cout << enemies.size() << '\n';
std::cout << enemies[i]->x << '\n';
}

// Call it like:
func(enemies);
```

If you pass the address of the vector, then you need to use some slightly wacky syntax, like:

```
std::cout << enemies->operator[](i).x << '\n';
```

So always use refrence in case of vectors

Comment: `enemies[i]` would be a pointer, you need to use `->` to access `x`